# Doctrine2 symfony2 multiple manytomany relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have a `Gift` entity, this entity has a sender, and a receiver...both from the entity `User`
a user can be a **sender** of many gifts to other users. but also a **receiver** of many gifts from many users

the way i see it, the solution inside my `Gift` entity would be like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tracker\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gift_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="gift_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $senders;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tracker\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gift_user",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="receiver_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="gift_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $receivers;
```

but when i run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` i get:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]                          
  The table with name 'finaldb.gift_user' already exists.
```

how do i have to change my syntax, configuration, so i end up with a table like this?

```
gift_id | sender_id | receiver_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible without two join tables.

Each `@ManyToMany` association requires a different join table. That because the join table does not know anything else than two linked entities (without knowing the direction of the association). Also, join tables generated by Doctrine ORM don't have any auto-incremental identifier, since the two references already represent the table's primary key.

Comment: thanks, so how do i solve the problem? important for me that the receiver is identivied,which is easily done....but how can i identify the sender in a clear way?workaround?

Comment: Completely missed notification about the comment, sorry.
If you have a receiver-sender structure, you may want to use a join entity with two fields, one referring to the sender and one to the receiver. This removes your `@ManyToMany` relation and replaces it with an entity so you can give a direction to the association.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the stuff : 
You can use joinTable to specific the join table name

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tracker\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gift_user",joinTable="myprefix_mytable_senders",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="sender_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="gift_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $senders;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tracker\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gift_user",joinTable="myprefix_mytable_receivers"
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="receiver_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="gift_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    protected $receivers;
```